# The term 'streamlit' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet object not found error

Tags: machine-learning, streamlit

The error image

[image: 1]

please check and any help will be very much apprecieted

Comment: Did you install streamlit?

Answer (score 0):

if you installed the streamlit & you are in the correct env but these error lingers, you can use

`py -m streamlit run app.py`

or

`python -m streamlit run app.py`

I hope it helps, if you have another question feel free to ask